# Action to event

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive

I have an `Action<Action> operation` which does some long-running work and sends heartbeats through the provided `Action` argument.
Before I invoke it, I want to set up an `IObservable<Unit>` that produces a Next element each time the operation sends a heartbeat.
**How do I do that?**

Creating the `IObservable` is [not that complicated](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html), but I’m guessing the conceptually easiest way would be [create it from an event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromevent%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), but sadly you cannot create an event in a method body (unless you know a way). I could use the [`Observable.FromEvent(Action<Action> addHandler, Action<Action> removeHandler)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244301%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), but that would require ugly closed-over Actions to forward method calls to (see example below).
Is there a more elegant way?

```
Action forward = null;
Action sendHeartbeat = () => { if (forward != null) forward(); };
//ugly, since it does not scale to multiple observers:
IObservable<Unit> heartbeatObs =
  Observable.FromEvent(handler => {
    forward = handler;
  }, _ => { forward = null; });
operation(sendHeartbeat);
```

Even if I did not use zero dimensional forward actions, but a collection thereof, it would be ugly because I’d be implementing the `+=` and `-=` operators for `EventHandlers` all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I've fully understood your question, but if I have, you could do something like this, which uses a `Subject` to transmit the heartbeats. You can find subjects in the namespace `System.Reactive.Subjects`.

```
 // set up a subject
 Subject<Unit> heartbeatSubject=new Subject<Unit>();

 // set up the heartbeataction to push units down the subject
 Action sendHeartbeat = () => { heartbeatSubject.OnNext(Unit.Default); };

 // use the heartbeat subject somehow.
 heartbeatSubject.Subscribe(_=>Console.WriteLine("Operation produced a heartbeat"));

 // start the operation
 operation(sendHeartbeat);
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in your comment, and according to the official RX line, using a subject is best avoided except in demo/example code. I've just had a go using Observable.Create, which might be better?

```
Action<Action> longRunningAction=(
    hb => { for(int i=0;i<100;i++) { hb(); Thread.Sleep(1000);}});

var ob=Observable.Create<Unit>(
(IObserver<Unit> observer) =>
{
    longRunningAction(()=>observer.OnNext(Unit.Default));
    return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed"));
});

ob.Subscribe(_=>Console.WriteLine("Received a heartbeat"));
```

Comment: That seems about as clean as it will get. Normally I don't like using subjects, as they create blobs of state in your Rx chain. However using a subject is much nicer than creating blobs of state by maintaining closed-over objects

Comment: Good point. I didn't think using a subject was so bad in this case, but then I read the IntroToRX page which said subjects are only for learning, and the preferred way to create observables is with Observable.Create. So I had a go with that - see edit above.

Comment: Your 2nd solution is indeed nice, avoiding subjects and everything. However, my initial question was a stripped down version of my actual problem: my long running action returns a result wrapped in a separate observable. For that situation I still like the subject solution, but I might ask a new question for the original problem.